# C# Xml deserialization with custom type member

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization, custom-type

I have an object to deserialize but the object has custom type `ApplicationLanguage` that cannot be serialize.

```
 [Serializable]
    public class FieldTranslation
    {
        // how is this possible?
        // does the 'en-us' in this member is reachable in this concept?
        //public ApplicationLanguage Lang = ApplicationLanguagesList.Get("en-us");

        //public ApplicationLanguage Lang { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        public string Tooltip { get; set; }

        public string Label { get; set; }

        public string Error { get; set; }

        public string Language { get; set; }
    }
```

I built an API to get type `ApplicationLanguage` from the cache like that:

```
ApplicationLanguage  en= ApplicationLanguagesList.Get("en-us");
```

Is there anyway that I can combine the custom type in the serialization above?

this is the xml:

```
 <Fields lang="en-us">
   <Item name="FirstName">
     <Tooltip>Please provide your {0}</Tooltip>
     <Error>{0} Is not valid</Error>
     <Label>First Name</Label>
  </Item>
</Fields>
```

Comment: Note; the `[Serializable]` here does nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could change your class struct like

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Fields")]
public class FieldCollection
{
    [XmlAttribute("lang")]
    public string Lanuage { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public FieldTranslation[] Fields { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class FieldTranslation
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Tooltip { get; set; }

    public string Label { get; set; }

    public string Error { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

and then set the language property to serialize

Answer (score 2):

Clarification: this answer is based on the pre-edit xml, where there was an

```
<Language>he</Language>
```

element. This answer does **not** apply to the `<Fields lang="en-us">` scenario.

Something like:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public ApplicationLanguage Lang { get; set; }

[XmlElement("Language")]
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public string LangSerialized {
    get { return Lang == null ? null : Lang.Name; } // or where-ever "he" comes from
    set { Lang = value == null ? null : ApplicationLanguagesList.GetByName(value); }
}
```

Here the `LangSerialized` member is used as a proxy to the short-form of `Lang`. With `XmlSerializer` it is required that this member is `public`, but I've added a few other attributes to make it disappear from most other common usages.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please have a look at my xml again and tell me how to navigate to the ` lang="en-us" ` thanks

Comment: @SexyMF ah, right; I incorrectly believed you were referring to the `<Language>` element. No, you couldn't do this from the `FieldTranslation` type - you'd need a wrapper, like Scott illustrates

Comment: @SexyMF (re accepted answer) my understanding is that Scott's answer more correctly reflects your scenario...

Answer (score 0):

You can manually fill a field in the collection above like this:

```
    [XmlAttribute("lang")]
    public string ManuallyFilledLang{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also could implement a `IXmlSerializable` interface in your ApplicationLanguage class